# How to get rid of the warning ".ts file is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused" if it comes from node_modules some library?

Tags: typescript, node-modules

tsconfig.app.json exclude property doesn't solve this problem

[tsconfig.app.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb6Iv.png)
Warnings still appear if i try to put these file paths to exclude property. If i go to the some_library and do the same there it works but only in this library and not in the main project.
Angular 16